# Не получается вывести имя с максимальным значением

Tags: javascript

Напиши функцию `findBestEmployee(employees)`, которая принимает объект сотрудников и возвращает имя самого продуктивного (который выполнил больше всех задач). Сотрудники и кол-во выполненных задач содержатся как свойства объекта в формате:

> "имя":"кол-во задач"

```js
const findBestEmployee = function(employees) {
  
};
 
console.log(findBestEmployee({
    ann: 29,
    david: 35,
    helen: 1,
    lorence: 99,
  }),
);

console.log(findBestEmployee({
    poly: 12,
    mango: 17,
    ajax: 4,
  }),
);
```

```
const findBestEmployee = function (employees) {
    const keys = Object.keys(employees);
    const firstEmployee = keys[0];
    let bestEmployee = firstEmployee;
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (employees[bestEmployee] > employees[key]) continue;
      bestEmployee = key;
    }
    return bestEmployee;
  };
```

Comment: Помочь или сделать за Вас?

Comment: "Не получается вывести имя", т.е. самого сотрудника-то вы уже нашли? Надо добавить в функцию выражение, начинающееся на `return`, тогда `console.log` успешно справится с задачей. Покажите, пожалуйста, код, либо будьте честны, что вы ничего не делали со своей стороны (а это уже похоже на нарушение правил сайта).

Comment: Вывожу имя а само значение незнаю как const findBestEmployee = function (employees) {
    const keys = Object.keys(employees);
    const firstEmployee = keys[0];
    let bestEmployee = firstEmployee;
    for (const key of keys) {
      if (employees[bestEmployee] > employees[key]) continue;
      bestEmployee = key;
    }
    return bestEmployee;
  };

Comment: нажмите кнопку "править" и вставьте, пожалуйста, код прямо в вопрос, в комментарии это нечитаемо, к сожалению

Comment: В вашем случае `bestEmployee` это имя, а `employees[bestEmployee]` - значение их можно вернуть оба, как, допустим, здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript, попробуйте

Comment: незнаю или так правельно, я добавил к return employees[bestEmployee]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const findBestEmployee = function(employees) {
  let emp = '';
  for (let key in employees)
    if (!(employees[key] <= employees[emp]))
      emp = key;
  // варианты на выбор:
  //return emp;
  //return { [emp]: employees[emp] };
  return { name: emp, score: employees[emp] };
};
 
console.log(findBestEmployee({
    ann: 29,
    david: 35,
    helen: 1,
    lorence: 99,
  })
);

console.log(findBestEmployee({
    poly: 12,
    mango: 17,
    ajax: 4,
  })
);
```